# How do I use ReorientObject() in an SQL Server 2012 UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to `UPDATE` a Geography field in an SQL Server 2012 database using the output of a web mapper.  I got the dreaded "The specified input does not represent a valid geography instance because it exceeds a single hemisphere," error when running the command. I found that [by reversing the order of the vertices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646985/inserting-geography-the-specified-input-does-not-represent-a-valid-geography-in) the `UPDATE` command works as expected.

I see that SQL Server 2012 includes a ReorientObject() method that does this task, but I don't know how to incorporate it into my SQL `UPDATE` command.  The following returns the same "single hemisphere" error.

```
UPDATE tblProjects
SET tblProjects.Boundary = geography::STGeomFromText( 'POLYGON ((-93.30388806760311 27.994401411046173, -94.62224744260311 33.37641235124676, -79.70281384885311 31.80289258670676, -93.30388806760311 27.994401411046173))',4326).ReorientObject()
WHERE tblProjects.ProjectID = 1 ;
```

Comment: I'd love to learn how to incorporate ReorientObject() on a simple select.

Answer (score 0):

This should update your column:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET column = column.MakeValid().ReorientObject();
```